# django-oscar integration error

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I integration ecommerce into my code. And run into problem with Product. When i update me `models.py` with simple

```
class MyProduct(AbstractProduct):
    pass
```

or even extend my `Package` model with AbstractProduct and try to create migrations the next error appears.

```
catalogue.Product.product_class: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Product.product_class' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Package.product_class'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Product.product_class' or 'Package.product_class'.
catalogue.Product.product_class: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Product.product_class' clashes with reverse query name for 'Package.product_class'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Product.product_class' or 'Package.product_class'.
catalogue.ProductAttributeValue: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'ckanwrap.Package.attributes', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Package' or 'ProductAttribute'.
catalogue.ProductCategory: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'ckanwrap.Package.categories', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Package' or 'Category'.
catalogue.ProductRecommendation: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'ckanwrap.Package.recommended_products', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Package' or 'Product'.
ckanwrap.Package.product_class: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Package.product_class' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Product.product_class'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Package.product_class' or 'Product.product_class'.
ckanwrap.Package.product_class: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Package.product_class' clashes with reverse query name for 'Product.product_class'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Package.product_class' or 'Product.product_class'.
ckanwrap.Package.recommended_products: (fields.E335) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'ckanwrap.Package.recommended_products', but it has more than one foreign key to 'Product', which is ambiguous. You must specify which foreign key Django should use via the through_fields keyword argument.
    HINT: If you want to create a recursive relationship, use ForeignKey("self", symmetrical=False, through="ProductRecommendation").
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Did you find the cause for this or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still getting this problem, the solution is to create a class with the same name used by oscar. In this case, it would be Product.

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct
from django.db import models


class Product(AbstractProduct):
     additional_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```